# DeprecationWarning: Creating streaming responses with `HttpResponse` is deprecated. Use `StreamingHttpResponse`?

Tags: python, django, httpresponse

Why am I seeing this error? Is there any problem in the `django` method below?

```
def email_send(request):

    data = json.loads(request.body)

    email_conf = getEmailConf(data)
    mail_message = getFormattedMsg(data)
    try:
        t = threading.Thread(target=send_mail,args=[email_conf['subject'],mail_message , email_conf['from_addr'],[email_conf['to_addr'],]],kwargs={'fail_silently':False})
        t.setDaemon(True)
        t.start()
    except:
        print "Exception in sending Mail:"
        print data
        print email_conf
    response= email_conf['response']
    try:
        if data['id']==8:
            response={'redirect2thankupage'}
    except:
        pass
    return HttpResponse(response)
```

Answer (score 2):

Django is *warning* you that in a future release, `HttpResponse` will only accept strings as content.

In the case where `data['id'] == 8` you are passing a `set`.  You can probably just pass a string here.

For reference, see the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse) and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#django.http.StreamingHttpResponse).